# Have VBA only work on certain workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code, and when I have the workbook with this open but I go on a different workbook it comes up with an error saying "subscript out of bounds". I have added the line specifing the workbook thinking this would stop it, but it doesn't seem to be solving anything. What alterations need to be made to avoid the error?

```
Option Explict
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("The wookbook I want it to work in")
Set wks = Sheets("The sheet I want it to work in")
Set cht = wks.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the macro to work with the active workbook:

```
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = wb.Activesheet
for each cht in wks.ChartObjects
     ....
next cht
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, this didn't quite work as it isn't the active workbook, but by doing Set wks = wb.Worksheets("the sheet") it did work.